# Calculation of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

So, I am having trouble trying to calculate

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+1}-x = \infty$$

Can you guys give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: $$(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)=?$$  OR set $x=\cot2y$

Comment: = (√(x^2+1))^2-x^2= x^2+1-x^2=1 that will never give me + infinite

Comment: wait I saw my mistake -(-infinite)= + infinite. Sorry, that was so simple...

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For $x < 0$
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1} - x  = \sqrt{x^2+1} + |x| > 2 |x| 
$$

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x<0$ we have

> $$+\infty = \lim_{x\to -\infty}|x|\le\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}\le\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2+1}-x$$

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Comment: @GiuR my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}-x>-x
$$
What is $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(-x)$?

Alternatively, observe this is not an “indeterminate form”, because it is $\sqrt{x^2+1}+(-x)$ and both summands have limit $\infty$.

---

Maybe your problem stems from trying to pull $x$ outside the square root, doing
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}=x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$
but this is a big mistake: for $x<0$, the left-hand side is positive, but the right-hand side is negative, so they cannot be equal. Remember that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, so, for $x<0$ (which you can assume, since you have a limit for $x\to-\infty$),
$$
\sqrt{x^2+1}=|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=-x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}
$$
Hence you can rewrite your limit as
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}-x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)
$$
where the term in parentheses has limit $2$, so we have $-(-\infty)\cdot2=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+1}-x = \lim_{y \to \infty} \sqrt{(-y)^2+1}-(-y)=\lim_{y \to \infty} \sqrt{y^2+1}+y=\infty+\infty=\infty$$